# Verify Signature of a MDNReceipt with C#

Tags: c#, public-key, x509certificate2

I'm developing an AS2 Client that has to communicate with a AS2 Server and verify the response message (MDN Receipt) integrity.
I have to verify that the signature on the MDN Receipt has been performed with the certificate of the Server, whose public key is shared with me (Client): so I have to verify that the signature on the response is performed with the private key linked to a specific public key.

The part of the response message that has been signed, the signature and the public key of the certificate is the following:

```
`var message = "Date: Mon, 5 Jun 2023 14:44:19 +0200 (CEST)\n" +"Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=disposition-notification;\n" +"    boundary=\"----=_Part_4263_1692287796.1685969059906\"\n" +"\n" +"------=_Part_4263_1692287796.1685969059906\n" +"Content-Type: text/plain\n" +"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +"\n" +"The AS2 message has been received.\n" +"------=_Part_4263_1692287796.1685969059906\n" +"Content-Type: message/disposition-notification\n" +"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +"\n" +"Reporting-UA: mendelson AS2\n" +"Original-Recipient: rfc822; mendelsontestAS2\n" +"Final-Recipient: rfc822; mendelsontestAS2\n" +"Original-Message-ID: <AS2_SVTest05062023_144419>\n" +"Disposition: automatic-action/MDN-sent-automatically; processed\n" +"Received-Content-MIC: KbBDmPLlBBpnlEOr64kWfETdR9YJVNSf3FNAzqP3V2g=, sha-256\n" +"\n" +"------=_Part_4263_1692287796.1685969059906--\n";
```

```
var signature = "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";
```

```
var publiKey = "MIIBCgKCAQEAyeDD3FzJD3GdWoMj4pcpX7XLc5ZWJyVmt7ci+hCIyVmc4Kz5JIhAqQmes/EYNBf1CHBQL6yLbVPzfmDhadoXcRtVtosyG6+XvTzP8zaUQ5NcEZPkOA8S14VcvPkIX4I7NuU5TKkgRQ6G91tnFg3F5Ywm79qBuggxa3VPSofQpq3bJXYkaNI8vMARFyX/bDjNYFzOYCyDjG6Jwbwg1M69DLK6IGntku6PXGOf3X2BPMNgiZfV29sGIBKoWyx4q3p0qLXKYTPAtYP9+Uzkz+mq2dcH56L6rFuAMbXYGEwarbby0JsVULc3q8+anlfxrfzDJH1KYzrdYmW6bRi/dh8AWQIDAQAB";`
```

I have tried all the solution proposed here in StackOverflow and elsewhere, but with this type of input it never works.

For example I have:

```
public static bool VerifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, byte[] publicKey, RSAParameters rsaParam){
    var verified = false;
```

```
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // Import public key
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);

            // Create signature verifier with the rsa key
            var signatureDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);

            // Set the hash algorithm to SHA256.
            signatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

            // Compute hash
            byte[] hash;
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
            }

            verified = signatureDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signature);
        }
        return verified;
    }
```

with

```
data = Convert.FromBase64String("dGF0b0Bmcm9td2luMzIuY29t"); 
signature = Convert.FromBase64String("lWKRRgWBA2lBAfUvBS+54s9kmHTH3nJwcvYYmjCg5QpWQ9joY7Rzpq0zZjOhyxASXoAN4Vz8+mqSqPWi/4DFH7947ZWZSbopPfxiI7jjDRMAVymG0B+dRVjiMow48ZvhgP/FGSZqeLAei77Z0aAmwN2TBxkClqBpt9uy+nkI7V/TJGAbbLcWfiPWNVOGsU0smoFDQLlJjkocahNSOqjj+9PPFVqbc/VVHQWsSoq1ZxtCPILFwPCCtUCDITXrU/riGMFJ282p/3rfhDJKYis9/izR98/zgBLRoCew8zu8Za4UNWaHaR3HP/6voQI2NiVSKtss1VjvwjwXYIOh56yeSw=="); 
publicKey = Convert.FromBase64String("MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp6HzbSgZPkJPfZJWydFAKdzUWlQcGHCTZhghg8HwHOfRZp3QZ/iiDORVzdIlW6XYPz76aAn8Nxm/v4NbsQsFPbwIcc7CPOJe21VT+7f6ocZ4kef0dqxUOGuK1FynrqzsAeYoaeTW+w/HElXODOEzZs3CfyE3d4hy3TTM/mVyQGV1FO/hHWB/zXq7ryQ8hXP/ueJimmJvitB7UweemRxvEYfVx52VVAgzg1RqVWeRj8L/obfm0lwQtIAHdDOnIi/cwpsyKQNikjMsf4dFgt14fcOgFdSG06jB840GnOsRZM04CWZQ9ttwAvoNGK/zjriRYGySQ4Ey0K0l5G3UVr56mQIDAQAB");
```

it works!

By replacing the first data, it no longer works!
What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?